# Estimate of mean weight?

Tags: statistics

An Argentinean Rancher, who raises miniature Llamas, wants to have an estimate of the mean weight of his herd. The herd could be regarded as being a Normal population, with variance 225 lbs.

He performs an independent random sampling, choosing 20 of the Llamas. The mean of the sample was 64.3 lbs.

The Rancher desires to have an error of 5%.

At what estimate did he arrive?

//I know how to calculate a confidence integral estimate with 95% certainty but this question has nothing to do with that and I do not even know where to start, i cannot find any equation for this in my book. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Zak, the margin of error is defined as the product  (critical value)(Standard deviation) , if you know the pop. standard deviation, and otherwise, it is the product (critical value)(Standard Error).http://stattrek.com/estimation/margin-of-error.aspx?Tutorial=AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is badly stated.  Clearly the rancher's estimate for the mean weight is $64.3$ lbs.  I believe you are supposed to come up with a $95\%$ confidence interval around that based on the $20$ samples and known variance (which should have units of lbs$^2$).  The only other interpretation I can see would be that he desires the confidence interval to be $\pm (64.3 \cdot 0.05)$, but then you should be asked to specify the number of llamas to weight to meet this requirement.